# What platform is best for simulating a stochastic process on a graph/network?

Tags: stochastic-processes, simulation

I'm simulating a dynamic process which was so far done only on a lattice, and Matlab was quite sufficient for that.

However, I can't seem to find a convenient way to model such a process on a graph such that there is clear visualisation of the process, and also return and storage of some relevant data at each stage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using $R$? For instance see http://statisticalrecipes.blogspot.com/2013/01/easy-introduction-to-markov-chains-in-r.html

For visualization [see here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026597/simple-markov-chain-in-r-visualization).

By the way, [this visualization looks really nice](http://setosa.io/blog/2014/07/26/markov-chains/), but runs in Javascript, not R.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't say anything simulating/visualising these processes on a graph...

Comment: There are plenty of libraries in $R$ for visualization. I've added a link.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Also, this is the visualisation of the underlying MC, and not the actual dynamical process on the network structure. Sometimes, the process may not even be a MC. Does that make sense?

Comment: Anyway, these are the tools you need. Good luck!